# Change color on element and immediately change back

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking for a good looking way to make a `li` blink or flash when its selected from a list. 
Would like the function to change the background color of the li when clicked, but then for it to immediately start fading back to its original (white) background.
Here is what I have so far- it makes the li turn red but then it stays red. 
(IMPORTANT: I'm a total beginner, and so I'm not married to the following way of making the li highlight and fade back, any other suggestions are welcome.)

"myfunction" triggered by clicking li:

```
function myfunction(){
this.className ="colll";
setInterval(function(){this.className ="";},1000);}
```

css:

```
.colll{background-color:red; -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
 -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
 -o-transition: all .5s linear;
 transition: all .5s linear;}
```

Comment: Your css class selector selects for class `colll` and the className you assign is `coll`.

Comment: @joeytje50 thanks and fixed, was a just a type-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a super simple one without JavaScript, if the goal is just quick and simple feedback.

http://codepen.io/justinmueller/pen/DLvnf

And one with the delay and no JavaScript:
http://codepen.io/justinmueller/pen/amDIB

Answer (score 0):

```
li {
    color: #2E90FF;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .5s linear;
    -o-transition: all .5s linear;
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
li:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

## [JSFiddle Live](http://jsfiddle.net/hCWAR/)